# Black Artifacts on Android in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, lg

I have an OpenGL ES 2 code base that runs on iOS, Android, and on PC via the PowerVR emulation libraries.

When I run this code on an LG Optimus G LGE971, I see black artifacts on my model:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/renderartifacts.png/

My first reaction was that the near clipping plane might be the issue, but because these artifacts appear on only select devices, I do not believe that is the issue. Any other ideas on what might be causing this?

Also, this isn't captured well in the above image, but the artifacts are not static -- they move around as the model rotates, etc.

Comment: Post your shader code, seems like it could be something in there which is not supported on those devices' chips.

Comment: Do you use textures for your model?

Comment: This can also might be a problem caused by z-figthing. Looks like blackened parts of model are coming out of grey (textured?) ones while they should be inner parts of weapon. Do you use different shaders/GL modes for parts of weapon? Please also provide code excerpt for drawing geometry. Have you tried it on another devices with Adreno 320 GPU?
Also, screenshot of correct rendering will be really, really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed.  I fixed the issue by using

```
glTexImage2D()
```

with NULL for the buffer when I set up my mipmap levels, and then using

```
glTexSubImage2D()
```

when uploading the texture data into each level.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe Lighting Calculation in shader code was wrong by mistake.

That looks like only using Ambient light without diffuse & specular.

also I want you to check whether you converted the texture from BGRA to RGBA.

Comment: The shader doesn't use any lighting information -- it simply does a texture lookup in the fragment shader.