# Ghosting on Android with OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I have an OpenGL ES 2 app running on Android.  I have tested on a few devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S2
- LG Optimus G
- HTC One X
- Kindle Fire
- Kindle Fire HD

And the app runs as expected.  However, there is a lingering issue on my Samsung Galaxy S3.  In my demo, I render a bunch of spheres.  I can also pan the camera around by touching and dragging my finger on the screen.

What I notice is "ghosting" when I move the camera.  It's difficult to describe, but I can see the previous outlines of the sphere as I move the camera.  And, I can continue to see the previous outlines as the camera moves.  I don't see all the previous outlines -- only the last few (it's difficult to quantify things here).  And, I only see the outlines within the sphere -- as far as I can tell, the previous outlines cease to exist outside of the sphere.

However, once the camera stops, the outlines catch up and disappear within ~1s.  Simply put, when things are stationary, everything renders correctly.

I recently had some texturing issues (related to mipmapping) and I solved them the other day.  The problem and solution are outlined here:

[Black Artifacts on Android in OpenGL ES 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011389/black-artifacts-on-android-in-opengl-es-2)

Could my texturing fix be related to this?  I realize that I'm leaving out A LOT of details, but I'm wondering if the symptoms are enough to go on?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Additional details:

- The ghosting does not show up when taking a screenshot using the NDK.
- A photo of the problem:

[image: Ghosting effect on S3]

Comment: A screenshot of this phenomenon would be REALLY helpful.

Comment: Also, post your glClearColor/glClear/glClearDepthf code. Perhaps you are not clearing the z buffer properly?

Comment: I'm trying to capture a screen via the NDK ([link](http://www.howtogeek.com/121121/how-to-take-android-screenshots-on-your-pc-with-the-android-sdk/))
But am not able to capture what I am seeing.  Maybe this gives more insight into the nature of the problem?
As for my clear code, this is it:
glClearColor( r, g, b, a );
glClearDepthf( clearZ );
glClearStencil( clearStencil );
glClear( mask );
Where:
r=0.145098
g=0.552941
b=0.749020
a=1.000000
clearZ=1.000000
clearStencil=0x00000000
mask=0x00004500

Comment: glClear settings seem fine. If you can't capture the artifact but you _can_ capture the screen, it seriously starts to sound like a device screen issue. Can you take a photo of it with another device? Also, have you tried more than one  SIII to make sure it's not that one device?

Comment: By doing MANY glFlush();glFinish(); calls (I was testing to see the impact of adding more of these calls after certain operations), my framerate is now ~4fps.  The slower framerate really exaggerates the ghosting.  However, when I take a screen capture via the NDK tool, none of the ghosted images appear.  Go figure ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to another S3 right now.  But, I did manage to take a photo with another phone.  Here is is: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/96/ghosting.png/)

Comment: So, the screenshot above was taken when I upload each mipmap level using glTexImage2D().  And again, when I take a screenshot via the NDK, I see no artifacts.  I then switched over to pre-allocating each mipmap level using glTexImage2D() (without providing any texture data), and then upload texture data to each level via glTexSubImage2D().  When I use the latter approach, I see missing mipmap levels in my NDK screen capture: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/195/missingmips.png/)

Comment: I have included the image in the main post, hopefully a brighter mind will recognize this effect. I don't know what causes it, but I'm not convinced it's mipmap related.

Comment: Something more to note:

I have a loading thread (for textures, index, and vertex buffers), a main thread, and a render thread.  Both the loading and render thread have their own EGL context.

On my LG Optimus G, I used to have select mipmap levels failing to render WITHOUT a call to glFlush() (on the loading thread) after calling glTexImage2d().  After adding the flush, the mipmap issues went away.

On the S3, the addition of the flush lessened the symptoms, but as the original screenshot shows, I still have some "weirdness" going on.

Hopefully this additional information helps?

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is on your phone, under Developer options, check the box to "Disable hardware overlays."

I'm not yet sure if there's a way to force this behavior when running your app.