# Black artifacts with open gl es 2.0 texture rendering on Certain devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, texture-mapping

While rendering a texture on some devices (only galaxy s3 mini confirmed) i got dark area flickering on the texture as described in this thread:

[Black Artifacts on Android in OpenGL ES 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011389/black-artifacts-on-android-in-opengl-es-2)

I'm not allowed to comment this thread (not enough credit) but I would like clarification from the author who solved this issue:

Could you explain a little more how you use `glTexImage2D()` and `glTexSubImage2D()` to solve this?

In code I got these lines to load the bitmaps: 
(As you can see I'm using `texImage2D` to load the bitmap, the android documentation about `gltexImage2D` only provides attribute types but no explaination)

```
...
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;

final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

if (bitmap == null) {
    if (LoggerConfig.ON) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Resource ID " + resourceId + " could not be decoded.");
    }

    glDeleteTextures(1, textureObjectIds, 0);
    return 0;
} 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjectIds[0]);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
...
```

edit:

tried to implement the solution according to the link in top but no luck, same flickering effect,
new code to load bitmap:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight() * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    IntBuffer ib = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();

    int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    for(int i=0; i<pixels.length; i++){
        ib.put(pixels[i] << 8 | pixels[i] >>> 24);
    }

    bitmap.recycle();

    byteBuffer.position(0);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA,      GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
```

Illustration of odd behavior, see the black area to the middle right in the image:

(I need 10 reputations just to post an image?!?!?)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61092317/blackflickering.jpg

Comment: I'd imagine you would get more than simple black lines if you passed **NULL** to `glTexImage2D (...)` and then tried to generate mipmaps from that. The entire base image would be indeterminate, so generating mipmaps from the base image would also be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the other question that you've referenced appears to be this: the author specified MipMaps when originally loading up his textures, and the MipMaps didn't work properly.  There's a possibility that he wasn't using `glTexImage2d` properly.

The artifact that he got was: when the texture unit tried to move from one MipMap level to the next, there was no information there, and it rendered a blank (apparently black) texture instead.  So, at least one level of his MipMap did get loaded.

I'm unsure if that author actually resolved his issue properly.  OpenGL can be incredibly specific about how you load textures into it, and even the smallest error in your code can cause a problem.  The problem may only occur on some platforms, so you get the impression that something is wrong with the device, but it still may be the code.

The best place to start is the Red Book: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html

And then: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml

All of the functions that you want to know about are outlined there.

There's a few details that aren't answered in your question.  Are you creating your own MipMaps by hand?  Are you wanting OpenGL to generate MipMaps automatically?

I would suggest starting with a simple texture, that has *no* MipMaps, just one level.  See if you can make that work.  If that fixes the problem, then start moving towards using MipMaps.

As for the original question, there isn't exactly a difference between loading your texture data with `glTexImage2D` or updating texture data with `glTexSubImage2D`.  `glTexImage2D` is used to **specify** a texture (ie: the width / height of the texture, which is different for each MipMap level), whereas `glTexSubImage2D` is used to **update** all or part of a texture that has already been specified by `glTexImage2D`.  In the second instance, you're just updating it with new texels.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and advices. I'm quite new to opengl so the use of gltexsubimage2d is new for me. I've removed the midmapping as I don't need it. (there is no scaling of my bitmaps and I've understand midmapping that you use it while scaling your image, avoiding opengl es to have a big bitmap in memory if you zoom out the image?) Anyway even without midmapping the issue is still the same. I'm beginning to think this is device specific. The bitmaps are rendered correctly on nearly all devices (samsung s4, htc x one, nexus 5, old devices... only the s3 mini on android 4.1 ...)

Comment: I've added an illustration to my original post (could only paste the link as one needs 10 reputations to be allowed to insert images!!) Maybe someone will recognize the artifact. I've noticed that the dark area appear the I the camera view is changed. I.e then the view of the scen is frozen the dark spot will not flicker / move.